# Does wireshark can capture https request?

Tags: wireshark

I have been working in wireshark. And I can able to capture the http request and capturing http packets using wireshark. And now I am capturing the https request. It seems does not capture the packets and when I right click-> follow-->tcp stream It shows the unreadable characters. Does wireshark can capture https request ?

Comment: Of course it can capture them, you are seeing them. it just can't decode them. That's the whole point of https.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Wireshark can decode HTTPS (and whole host of other TLS/SSL implementations) as well, as long as you can provide the private key the HTTPS server uses. https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL

Comment: There is a pretty neat tutorial available here http://russell.ballestrini.net/how-to-capture-https-ssl-tls-packets-with-wireshark/